# VBA copy/paste a dynamic range in summary sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA, and most of the times I manage to fit my needs by simple jury-rigging someone else's code - sometimes I also find exactly what I was looking for in answers to other people's questions. But right now it seems I can't figure out how to solve this problem (I tried asking in other excel forums, but with no result).

I'm  working with very large data output files, which present all the variables I need to analyze scattered in sheets, in multiple workbooks. In order to statistically analyze these data files we often have to rearrange the output data into a more statistically friendly format. 
What I'm trying to code is a Summary new sheet for each of the workbooks I need analyzed, which will be populated with a dynamic range copied from each of the sheets and pasted one below the other.

The difficulty resides in the fact that the range is not fixed: has a variable starting point as row in column "A", and a variable length (and thus a variable ending point, but always in Column "F").

So I would need to adapt a simple copy/paste code like the one I've been using for ages

```
Sub SummurizeSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Summary").Activate

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
        ws.Range("A1:A2").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

with a dynamic range starting in:
Column "A", *`row =(MATCH(Summary!$M$1;[SheetName]!A:A;0)`*
and ending in the last non-blank cell starting from the range-start point (which is effectively the last populated cell within the range belonging to the variable described in the Summary Column M1)

this last part looks like frankenstein's monster as:
*`MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE("A";MATCH(Summary!$M$1`;`[SheetName]!A:A;0));":";"A100")));0;0);0)+ROW(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A";MATCH(Summary!$M$1;[SheetName]!A:A;0))))-1`*

which basically looks for the first blank cell in an arbitrary custom range, from the above-mentioned starting point to A100, and, once found, offsets the row number by (-1).

Finally, the question: how can I translate those two cell references into the *`ws.Range("xx:xx")`* above to have my old pal copy/paste do its job with the range I require?

Comment: what is the output of your frankenstein formula?

Comment: If you have two cell references you can just use `Range(reference1, reference2)`. The references can be either string or range objects.

Comment: @gizlmeier it's a row number

Answer (score 0):

If the output is a row number, just use `Cells()` in a combination with `Range()`:

```
Range(Cells(ROW NUMBER, COLUMN NUMBER), Cells(ROW NUMBER2, COLUMN NUMBER2))
```

where the `ROW NUMBER` is the output of your frankenstein and the `COLUMN NUMBER` is obviously the number of the column. `ROW NUMBER2` is the row number of your last row